# How to dump&restore a postgresql type in custom binary format?

Tags: sql, postgresql

for postgresql 9.3 or higher.

if i create a type with:

```
CREATE TYPE x(INPUT=x_in,OUTPUT=x_out,SEND=x_send,RECEIVE=x_receive,...);
```

then for all selects and from string casts `x_in` and `x_out` is used which is desired. however my type sometimes may hold additional informations which are unrelevant for the user - hence i should not show it in `x_out` but if the database is dumped/restored the extra information should be kept.

i've tryed to define `SEND` and `RECEIVE` which are working if i call them directly, but i was unsuccessful to force `pg_dump` to use them during creating the dump

binary dump creation/restoration:

```
 pg_dump -Fc db --table t > dump.bin
 pg_restore -d db -Fc dump.bin
```

NOTE: if i would show the additional data in the standard `x_out`, then the dumps and everything would be fine, but there are some third party tools which became confused about the format

Comment: `pg_dump`'s `-Fc` flag is the custom format: it's only binary because it uses compression. I'm afraid it has nothing to do with custom types' external binary representation.

Comment: If this information is irrelevant to a user, presumably it doesn't have to be present in the INSERT or COPY statement that creates the data. Then why would pg_dump include it? The pg_dump output is conceptually just the SQL a user would type to recreate a db from scratch.

Comment: irrelevant to the user, but the program may behave differently if it's lost in a dump/restore cycle

Comment: i'm currently thinking in the following direction: change the default `x_out` function to reflect all data, and provide some convinience method for the user to access the part he's usually intrested